# I'm making mistakes dividing large numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in python 2.7 that will first see if a number divides the other evenly, and if it does get the result of the division.

However, I am getting some interesting results when I use large numbers.

Currently I am using:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
a=82348972389472433334783
b=2
if a/b==math.trunc(a/b):
    answer=a/b
    print 'True' #to quickly see if the if loop was invoked
```

When I run this I get:

```
True
```

But 82348972389472433334783 is clearly not even.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Won't you bee looking to check the modulus of `a` divided by 2? I'd recommend changing your `if` to `if a % 2:`. This will give you `0` if `a` is even,`1` if `a` is odd. Because what I believe you're effectively doing is comparing whether `a/b` equals `a/b` (you're dividing integers, so `trunc` has no effect, right?)

Comment: Result of the division is a floating point number. You simply asks "[is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)"

Comment: @user2357112 The result of division *is* a float, because `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @jme: oh what how did I miss that never mind

Comment: Compare `a//b` and `math.trunc(a/b)`. They are very different. Your machine's `double` type doesn't have enough precision to accurately store `a/b`.

Comment: @wim Oops. By the way, I laughed at the edited title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a crazy way to do it.  Just use the remainder operator.

```
if a % b == 0:
    # then b divides a evenly
    quotient = a // b
```

Comment: That would let me know if it is divided evenly, but how would I know what the exact result would be? I need to know the exact division if it is evenly divisible later on in my code.

Comment: @wim my problem comes from the fact that when I do a/b with from __future__ import division it gives me the wrong answer. Would using quotient=a//b not make that mistake?

Comment: @Dan `a//b` does not produce a floating point result, so there is no error here. `quotient` is the correct result (when it is divisible)

Comment: @zvone When I do a//b in my code it still gives me a decimal not an integer. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Dan `//` produces float if it is dividing floats. `1.0//1` is `1.0`, but with integers inputs, the results is an integer (int or long): `1000000000000000//2` is `500000000000000L`

Answer (score 1):

The true division implicitly converts the input to floats which don't provide the precision to store the value of `a` accurately. E.g. on my machine

```
>>> int(1E15+1)
1000000000000001
>>> int(1E16+1)
10000000000000000
```

hence you loose precision. A similar thing happens with your big number (compare `int(float(a))-a`).
Now, if you check your division, you see the result "is" actually found to be an integer

```
>>> (a/b).is_integer()
True
```

which is again not really expected beforehand.

The math.trunc function does something similar (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)): 
*Return the Real value x truncated to an Integral (usually a long integer).*

The duck typing nature of python allows a comparison of the long integer and float, see 
[Checking if float is equivalent to an integer value in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6209008/2870069) and 
[Comparing a float and an int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037115/comparing-a-float-and-an-int-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the modulus operator instead to check if a number can be divided evenly?

n % x == 0