# square root of a number greater than 10^2000 in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, large-data, largenumber, square-root

I'd like to calculate the square root of a number bigger than 10^2000 in Python. If I treat this number like a normal integer, I will always get this result back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 3, in <module>
    print( q*(0.5)  )
OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

How do I fix this? Or does a possibilty other than using Python exist to calculate this square root?

Comment: Do you mean `10^2000` or `10**2000`?

Comment: `math.isqrt()` gives the truncated integer square root of an integer argument, even if the argument is too big to fit in a float. Does that meet your requirements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual square root methods convert the parameter to a float value before doing the calculation. As you saw, this does not work well with very large integers.

So use a function that is designed to work on arbitrarily large integers. Here is one, guaranteed to return correct integer part of the square root of any positive integer. This function drops the fractional part of the result, which may or may not be what you want. Since this function uses iteration it is also slower than the built-in square root routines. The Decimal module works on larger integers than the built-in routines but the precision of the values must be defined in advance so it does not work on arbitrarily large values.

```
import math

_1_50 = 1 << 50  # 2**50 == 1,125,899,906,842,624

def isqrt(x):
    """Return the integer part of the square root of x, even for very
    large integer values."""
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('square root not defined for negative numbers')
    if x < _1_50:
        return int(math.sqrt(x))  # use math's sqrt() for small parameters
    n = int(x)
    if n <= 1:
        return n  # handle sqrt(0)==0, sqrt(1)==1
    # Make a high initial estimate of the result (a little lower is slower!!!)
    r = 1 << ((n.bit_length() + 1) >> 1)
    while True:
        newr = (r + n // r) >> 1  # next estimate by Newton-Raphson
        if newr >= r:
            return r
        r = newr
```

Comment: "guaranteed to return correct integer part of the square root of any positive integer" — it appears that it is not true for my case: `isqrt(178533196125860586848256)=422531887702 != math.sqrt(178533196125860586848256)=422531887703`. My calculator also gives 422531887703. I tried it with Python 3.5.2 x64

Comment: @Dmitry: As I check your comment, I see that my `isqrt` is correct and the othe calculations are wrong. You can see that mine is correct by evaluating `422531887702**2 <= 178533196125860586848256 < 422531887703**2` in Python. That evaluates to `True`. However, `422531887703**2 <= 178533196125860586848256` evaluates to `False`. If the other methods say the correct square root is `422531887703` then they are wrong. Please check for yourself. If you find an actual error in my code, I would love to know, so please tell me.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thank you for the check. Yes, you are correct — your implementation gives accurate whole part while `math.sqrt` behaves very strange with big numbers: `math.sqrt(178533196125860602616209) == math.sqrt(178533196125860586848256)` returns True!

Comment: As far as I can see, the `if n <= 1` is always false because of the preceding `if x < _1_50: return int(math.sqrt(x))`.

Comment: I'm getting a substantial discrepancy with this one: 1234592592962967901296297037045679133590224789902207663928489902170626521926687. Every large sqrt method that I try returns 1111122222333334444455555666667777799903. which I don't believe to be correct

Comment: @J.Win.: My `isqrt` returns a number different from the one you show. Your number ends `903` while my `isqrt` returned number ends `003`. The rest of the digits agree. My testing shows my result to be correct. Please double-check the results that you get and your tests on the results.

Comment: @RoryDaulton @Dmitry as regards 422531887703, that is in fact the correct _square root_. 422531887702 is the correct _isqrt_. They are two different things! The reason for the discrepancy is that the former is correctly rounded, while the latter is not... such is the nature of `isqrt`.

Comment: @J.Win. The _correctly rounded square root_ of your number is `1111122222333334444455555666667777799004`. The _truncated square root_ (or `isqrt`) of your number is `1111122222333334444455555666667777799003`.

Answer (score 14):

Just use the decimal module:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal(10**2000).sqrt()
Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000E+1000')
>>> Decimal(10**200000).sqrt()
Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000E+100000')
>>> Decimal(15**35315).sqrt()
Decimal('6.782765081358674922386659760E+20766')
```

You can also use the [gmpy2 library](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/).

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> n = gmpy2.mpz(99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999982920000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000726067)
>>> gmpy2.get_context().precision=2048
>>> x = gmpy2.sqrt(n)
```

Useful links:

1. [Decimal - Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

Comment: If you are looking for an integer result and are going to use `gmpy2`, the simplest and best way is just `gmpy2.isqrt().

Comment: @casevh note: `isqrt` will not round the square root correctly--it gives the floor of the square root instead of the nearest integer.

Comment: @HansBrende Then take a look at `gmpy2.isqrt_rem()`. It also returns the remainder and that can be used to calculate the ceiling or nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

When using `sqrt` from the library [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), before it proceeds to square root it, it will convert the value to a float.

If we manually try to convert the `10**2000` to a float, it also triggers an error

```
>>> float(10**2000)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6ac81f63106d> in <module>
----> 1 math.sqrt(10**2000)

OverflowError: int too large to convert to float
```

If we were speaking of a big number, but with the square equals or less than 308, the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module would do the work as follows

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(math.sqrt(10**308))
Decimal('10000000000000000369475456880582265409809179829842688451922778552150543659347219597216513109705408327446511753687232667314337003349573404171046192448274432')
```

However, as the number is way square is way bigger than 308, in this case, 2000, one would have to do as follows

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(10**2000).sqrt()
Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000E+1000')
```

Let's see the output if one tries to convert the `Decimal(10**2000)` to float

```
>>> float(Decimal(10**2000))
inf
```

One might also use the decimal module when working with factorials, as they tend to get large really fast.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal module is fine but involves the added overhead of converting from base 2 to base 10 and back, plus it is non-obvious how much decimal precision is necessary to get the result back into base 2, correctly rounded.

Without using decimal, it is slightly trickier to compute the square root since this is not built-in functionality, but it's still possible using `math.isqrt` instead! Here's a function I came up with that calculates the square root of any number to arbitrary precision, *correctly rounded*:

```py
def sqrt(x: Union[int, float, Fraction], precision: int = 53) -> Fraction:
    a, b = x.as_integer_ratio()
    la, lb = a.bit_length(), b.bit_length()
    s = max(precision - (la + lb - (a << lb < b << la) >> 1), 0)
    ab = a * b << (s << 1)
    n0 = math.isqrt(ab)
    n1 = n0 + 1
    return Fraction(n1 if n0 * n1 < ab else n0, b << s)
```

More precisely, the following are guaranteed to hold:

- `|√(x) - sqrt(x, p)| < 0.5ulpₚ(√(x))`
- `float(sqrt(x, 53)) == math.sqrt(x)` if `math.sqrt(x)` doesn't overflow
- `sqrt(x * x) == x`, avoiding [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551529/why-is-math-sqrt-incorrect-for-large-numbers)

If you need the result as a `float` instead of a `Fraction`, just do `float(sqrt(x))` (although this may lose precision or overflow if the final result is too big for a float).

**Note:** if you know in advance that you will only be taking the square root of integers, there is a slightly simpler function that does the same thing, but only works on integers. The above function is equivalent to this one for any integer or `Fraction` with a denominator of 1:

```py
def sqrt_of_int(x: int, precision: int = 53) -> Fraction:
    s = max(precision - (x.bit_length() + 1 >> 1), 0)
    x <<= s << 1
    n0 = math.isqrt(x)
    n1 = n0 + 1
    return Fraction(n1 if n0 * n1 < x else n0, 1 << s)
```