# how can i convert string to float in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

so i am struggling on understanding converting string to float in python.

i am using a csv file and i want each row of item to be a list, the food name to be a string, the carbs to be a string, and calories to be float

i don't understand how to do that i am trying this:

```
def menu_list(filep):
    """Function to read the csv file, create a nested list and return the list that is sorted based on calories in the ascending order."""

    menulist = [] #store items
    with open(filep) as csv_file: #read file
        csv_reader = csv.reader (csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader, None)

        mlist = []
        for row in csv_reader:
            row = str
            row[2] = float()
            print (row)

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    return menulist
```

every time i run this it give me the error : 'type' object does not support item assignment

can someone help me fix my code and convert string to float?

Comment: what does your csv file look like? Can you give a few lines as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing with your csv output.
To answer your main question you can use `my_float = float(my_str)`

In your example, you are asking how to convert an individual column in your csv. 
This is dependent on your data. Say you have a csv row like this.

```
"Apple","25 g",95
```

Since your `float` is unquoted it's really helpful when parsing the csv.
We can simply specify unquoted as numeric in our `csv.reader()` object.

```
import csv

def menu_list(filep):
    """
    Function to read the csv file, 
    create a nested list and return the list that is 
    sorted based on calories in the ascending order.
    """

    menulist = [] #store items
    with open(filep) as csv_file: #read file
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, 
                                delimiter=',', 
                                quotechar='"', 
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        next(csv_reader, None)

        for row in csv_reader:
            menulist.append(row)

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    return menulist
```

However, if all or none of your columns in your csv are quoted, you'll have to parse as you're appending

```
"Apple","25 g","95"
```

or

```
Apple,25 g,95
```

```
import csv

def menu_list(filep):
    """
    Function to read the csv file, 
    create a nested list and return the list that is 
    sorted based on calories in the ascending order.
    """

    menulist = [] #store items
    with open(filep) as csv_file: #read file
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(csv_reader, None)

        for row in csv_reader:
            row[2] = float(row[2].strip())
            menulist.append(row)

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    return menulist
```

Comment: Is there any way so that it converts float to int if there isn't any decimal point?

Comment: (apart from the obvious solution `int(x) if isinstance(x, float) and x.is_integer() else x` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209008/checking-if-float-is-equivalent-to-an-integer-value-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to float easily.

```
string_num = "555.555"
print(float(string_num)) #It's float now.
```

If there is non-number your variable, you can use regex. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703390/how-to-extract-a-floating-number-from-a-string)

Comment: i get this one but inside a csv file i need to make the items to be a string the other item to be int and the an item which is a string to be a float